# Find Error Line Number in VBA

Tags: vba

I'm trying to find the line number where my code crashes but many explanation on this site seems to complicated for my level.

My code is basically as below and I have no idea where it's breaking.

```
Sub1   
    Call function1  
    Call function2  
End Sub
```

Other answers on this website seems to be just a short function. But I don't know where to call the function in my code or how to get a popup message. If I'm meant to put my sub1 code into their function, I don't know where either. Beginner here.

Comment: Aren't you taken to the code where the error occurred when you press `Debug` on prompt ? Also that should be `Sub One()` instead of `Sub1`

Comment: "My code is basically as below". Is there any reason why you are posting something which is "basically" your code rather than your actual code?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If your code doesn't have *line numbers*, then VBA has no way of giving you *line numbers*.

You *can* write VBA and make it look 1980-like to do this:

```
Sub1
On Error GoTo 100
10   Call Function1
20   Call Function2
90   Exit Sub
100  Debug.Print Err.Message & " on line " & Erl
End Sub
```

But you don't want to do that. Really, you don't *need* a line number.

You need smaller functions that *handle runtime errors*.

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
```

When a runtime error occurs, execution jumps to the *line label* called `ErrHandler`.

```
     ...
     Exit Sub
ErrHandler: '<< the line label is denoted with a colon
```

What goes in that handler? If you're debugging, you might want to just `Stop` execution there and inspect your locals:

```
    Stop
```

Then add `Resume` on the next line, and press <kbd>F8</kbd> to *step into* it. `Resume` will return to the call that caused the error. If that's a function call, then you need to handle runtime errors in that function.

Make sure you never leave `Stop` and `Resume` instructions in production code:

```
Sub WhenWillThisEnd()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Debug.Print 42/0
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Resume 'jumps back to the line that caused the error
    Resume Next 'resumes execution on the line right after the one that went boom
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't know about `Erl` despite programming  VBA for over a decade. I love Stack Overflow -- you learn something new every day.

Comment: me too, 5 yrs in VBA, now only i think about this. There was a time i saw someone's code who label every line with numbers and was thinking why the h*** would someone label every lines... Now i know why :D

Comment: Does this code block mean its execution never ends? And, is this same as `On Error Resume Next`<...code...>`On Error GoTo 0` combo? I'm just trying to reconcile the error handling shown here with ones that I've found to be most common.

Comment: @KarthickGanesan `On Error Resume Next` supresses error handling, allowing execution to continue to the next statement instead of jumping to a handler subroutine. Use it wisely, because it's very easy to shoot your foot off that way: always limit the statements allowed to run in an unhandled error state - `On Error GoTo 0` restores error handling by clearing the error context, making the next run-time error unhandled, and prevents OERN from "leaking" outside its scope (that's an edge case: *normally* error context is reset on procedure exit with OERN; best be systematic about OEG0).

Comment: Also yes, the snippet at the bottom is an (implicit) infinite loop thart will eventually hang the host - do not run without breakpoints (F9) and stepping-through (F8) with the debugger!

Comment: I created a global variable to set debugging mode. Also, in order to avoid the infinite loop, I added a few lines of code to count the number of times that the error occurs (also with a global variable). After some predefined limit, I run an `EXIT SUB` statement.