# Using IFERROR in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I hope someone can help me please?  I've done a lot of googling and can't figure out what the issue is.  I only dabble in vba, so I'm certainly no expert...

I am trying to automate some calculations in a huge spreadsheet at work, and I think I'm probably missing something really silly.  Basically, one of the calculations is a simple divide of one cell by another cell.  When it hits an error, I want it to return a 0.  Here is the code that keeps tripping over:

```
Sheets("Bridge").Range("W" & SumIfInt) = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Sheets("Bridge").Range("AA" & SumIfInt) / Sheets("Bridge").Range("D" & SumIfInt), 0)
```

I get a Run-time error 6 Overflow

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this without If error function. As mentioned below, you should use On error resume next very carefully.

Warning: `On error resume next` will skip ALL cases of error for rest of the code unless `On error goto 0` is present. Also, if you would like to catch a specific error, you can use `if error = 'number' then` to handle them accordingly. Application.worksheetfunction.iserror is better used in excel, than in excel vba.

```
    On error resume next
    Sheets("Bridge").Range("W" & SumIfInt) = Sheets("Bridge").Range("AA" & 
    SumIfInt) / Sheets("Bridge").Range("D" & SumIfInt)

    if err <>0 then
       Sheets("Bridge").Range("W" & SumIfInt) = 0
    end if
    On error goto 0
```

Comment: Good (+1) ... but don't leave `on error resume next` active! Put the line `on error goto 0` after the `end if` (as a stylistic point, in the rare cases that I use `on error resume next` I indent the statements where it is in force and then only return to the previous indentation level after I turn it off).

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I downvoted not because of `On Error Resume Next` being terrible advice to give a newbie, but because "try this: {code dump}" copy-pasta answers that don't teach anything aren't worthy of being posted in my opinion. Telling a new VBA coder to stick `On Error Resume Next` **without mentioning anything about the deadly pitfalls of this terrible practice** is what earns my downvote. Feel free to [edit] and improve your answer anytime if you would like that vote reversed.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Good points. I upvoted since checking `err.number` is good practice and is rare in the sort buggy uses of `On Error Resume Next` which routinely pop up on Stack Overflow, though it would definitely be appropriate to include proper warnings on that construct (including turning it off after the problematic statement). Hopefully Middle will edit this question.

Comment: @JohnColeman `Err <> 0` is *implicitly* checking for `Err.Number`, through `ErrObject`'s *default member*. This `err <>0` part is obscuring elements of knowledge; `Err` being a function that returns an `ErrObject`, a better practice would be to wrap it in a `With Err` block, and explicitly invoke its `.Number` property. But yeah, OERN+Err.Number check is perfectly fine - as long as it's explained properly =)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks for pointing this out, I'm fairly new to stackoverflow as well. I did not consider that this answer will be archived and searched in the future. Will becareful from now on, thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to edit your contribution - upvoted!

Comment: @Mat'sMug Out of interest what would be gained by using the Err block? I suppose Err.Source is useful. I wish VBA had Err.Erl to get the offending line.

Comment: @Absinthe see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36554214/1188513) - VBA *does* have an `Erl` function. Note that it only has `Integer` resolution, while `Long` line numbers are pefectly legal (which makes it broken by definition). Also it returns the *last encountered line number*, which means you *must* write 1980-ish code in order to use it. The offending line is pretty damn easy to get to, once you know how to use the debugger (see linked answer). A `With Err` block avoids dereferencing the same `ErrObject` instance over and over every time you get a property.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Eeew, icky :) Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 9):

When programming it's always best to avoid an error by checking for it's possibility first, rather than triggering one then dealing with it. Check if the cell is empty or zero before performing the calculation:

```
If IsEmpty(Sheets("Bridge").Range("D" & SumIfInt)) Or Sheets("Bridge").Range("D" & SumIfInt) = 0 Then
    Sheets("Bridge").Range("W" & SumIfInt) = 0
Else
    Sheets("Bridge").Range("W" & SumIfInt) = Sheets("Bridge").Range("AA" & SumIfInt) / Sheets("Bridge").Range("D" & SumIfInt)
End If
```

On Error Resume Next basically says "If you encounter an error just ignore it". This can cause all sorts of unexpected problems and should only be used as a last resort.

Also check out the [IsError](http://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-iserror-function.html) function in VBA.

Comment: Of course OP accepts the `On Error Resume Next` solution. Good news: we'll see that OP again soon.

Answer (score 4):

What is the declared type of `SumIfInt`? If that's `Integer`, its maximum legal value is 32,767, because `Integer` is a 16-bit type - and using a 16-bit signed integer type to represent row numbers in an Excel worksheet is a good way to achieve run-time error 6 "Overflow".

Use a 32-bit integer type instead:

```
Dim SumIfInt As Long
```

If `Sheets("Bridge").Range("D" & SumIfInt)` is a very small value, it's possible that using it as a denominator makes the result overflow an `Integer`, or possibly even a `Long` - in that case you should probably use a `Double` floating-point type instead.

> When it hits an error, I want it to return a 0.

Better code wouldn't hit an error at all. The only error you *should* be worried about here, is "Division by Zero" - actually also "Type Mismatch" if any of the involved cells may contain an error value - in any case, shoving the error under the carpet with `On Error Resume Next` isn't showing you anything about how to avoid that situation in the future.

The best error-handling code is code that *avoids* raising avoidable errors in the first place.

```
Dim divisorValue As Variant 
divisorValue = Sheets("Bridge").Range("D" & SumIfInt)

If IsError(divisorValue) Or IsEmpty(divisorValue) Then
    ' return 0 and bail out
    Exit Function
End If

Dim divisor As Double
divisor = CDbl(divisorValue)
```

Now use the known-to-be-ok `divisor` value instead.

A note about your object management: you're dereferencing the exact same object reference multiple times - that's inefficient.

If `Sheets("Bridge")` exists at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook` (the workbook that's running the code), then you **never** need to dereference it that way - VBA creates a global-scope object variable for every single worksheet in the workbook - select it in the VBE's *Project Explorer* (Ctrl+R), bring up its *Properties* (F4), then set its `(Name)` to something meaningful, e.g. `BridgeSheet`. Then you can do this:

```
BridgeSheet.Range("D" & SumIfInt)
```

Another tip: the more you cram into a single instruction, the harder debugging becomes, because the more possible failing points there are.

Consider pulling the invidividual values involved into their own variables, then validating them, *then* performing the division once you **know** doing that isn't going to blow up.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid creating errors in the first place - `On Error` should generally be used to handle unexpected errors.
The reasoning behind this is that if a genuine error occurred after the `On Error Resume Next` it would be ignored and your sum would be 0.
*E.g.* If someone wrote *Five hundred* instead of a *500* you'll just get a 0 (far fetched, but ... actually, not far fetched - never under estimate a sufficiently talented idiot).

Anyway....

If `Sheets("Bridge").Range("D" & SumIfInt)` is zero or empty you'll get a division by 0 error.
Providing everything else is correct (no text, all other numbers present) then this is the only figure you need to check:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim SumIfInt As Long
    SumIfInt = 2

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bridge")
        If .Range("D" & SumIfInt) = 0 Then
            .Range("W" & SumIfInt) = 0
        Else
            .Range("W" & SumIfInt) = .Range("AA" & SumIfInt) / .Range("D" & SumIfInt)
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
On Error Resume Next 'Disable break when error occurs
'Enter the code you want to error check, say a cell reference, here.
If Err.Number >0 Then 'Err.Number=0 only if there were no errors
'Enter what you want happening if there was an error
Else
'Enter what you want happening if there is no error
End if
On Error GoTo 0 'Delete error message and re-activate break when (a new) error occurs
```

Comment: This is a stripped, worse formatted version of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48152507/11683) posted 6 years prior.