# How to solve "error 70 permission denied"?

Tags: vba, web-scraping

[Example of what code do for day 20/04/2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VgP9.png)

I'm trying to scrape some odds from oddsportal for some leagues. But since I open too many links, after some time my code stops and shows me the following error:

> Run-time error '70': Permission denied.

I tried putting some delay in the code but the error persists. Could someone please help me?

```
Sub test()

Dim IE() As Object
Dim IE1 As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim link1x2 As String
Dim linkover As String
Dim linkbtts As String

''Novo código
Set IE1 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE1.Visible = False
IE1.Navigate "https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/20190420"

Do While IE1.Busy Or IE1.ReadyState <> 4
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set doc = IE1.Document
Set jogos = doc.getElementsByClassName("deactivate")
ReDim IE(0 To jogos.Length * 3)
i = 2
j = 0

For Each jogo In jogos
    URL = jogo.Children(1).Children(0).href

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set IE(j) = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    link1x2 = URL & "#1X2;2"
    IE(j).Visible = False
    IE(j).Navigate link1x2

    Do While IE(j).Busy Or IE(j).ReadyState <> 4
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set doc = IE(j).Document
    Set equipas = doc.getElementById("col-content").Children(0)
    Set liga = doc.getElementsByClassName("home")(0).Children(0).Children(3)


    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    For k = 1 To 25
        If liga.innerText = Worksheets("Plan2").Range("A" & k) Then
            Worksheets("Plan1").Range("M" & i) = liga.innerText
            Worksheets("Plan1").Range("A" & i) = equipas.innerText
            oddH = doc.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).Children(1).innerText
            oddD = doc.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).Children(2).innerText
            oddA = doc.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).Children(3).innerText

            Worksheets("Plan1").Range("C" & i) = oddH
            Worksheets("Plan1").Range("D" & i) = oddD
            Worksheets("Plan1").Range("E" & i) = oddA

            Set IE(j + 1) = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
            linkbtts = URL & "#bts;2"
            IE(j + 1).Visible = False
            IE(j + 1).Navigate linkbtts

            Do While IE(j + 1).Busy Or IE(j + 1).ReadyState <> 4
                Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
            Loop

            Set doc = IE(j + 1).Document

            oddBTTS = doc.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).Children(1).innerText
            oddNBTTS = doc.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).Children(2).innerText

            Worksheets("Plan1").Range("G" & i) = oddBTTS
            Worksheets("Plan1").Range("H" & i) = oddNBTTS
            IE(j + 1).Quit

            Set IE(j + 2) = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
            linkover = URL & "#over-under;2;2.50;0"
            IE(j + 2).Visible = False
            IE(j + 2).Navigate linkover

            Do While IE(j + 2).Busy Or IE(j + 2).ReadyState <> 4
                Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
            Loop

            Set doc = IE(j + 2).Document

            oddover = doc.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).Children(2).innerText
            oddunder = doc.getElementsByClassName("aver")(0).Children(3).innerText

            Worksheets("Plan1").Range("J" & i) = oddover
            Worksheets("Plan1").Range("K" & i) = oddunder
            IE(j + 2).Quit
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next k
    IE(j).Quit
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    j = j + 1
Next jogo
End Sub
```

Comment: it's a list of 25 countrys ( Argentina, Portugal , England , France, Germany , ... )

Comment: You know some good books to help me improving on web-scrapping vba ? I really want to improve and learn more and more, and since i like read books it could help me a lot .

Comment: I don't know about books. Resources: https://www.youtube.com/user/WiseOwlTutorials/search?query=web-scraping , https://flukeout.github.io/ , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors , https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/

Comment: How is the code? :) Still in progress?

Comment: I had written a full answer which just bloody disappeared with internet drop. One second and will write up and post again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr;**

One of the immediately obvious issues is the repeated creation of IE instances when only one is needed. `Permission denied` can occur for a number of reasons including not handling/disposing of objects properly.

The following shows you how to:

1. Work more efficiently with a single IE instance
2. Use a helper function to gather all the urls to visit and filter on countries of interest
3. Correctly retrieve `liga` value and assign country to a `country` variable
4. Navigate to pages and between tabs accurately. Simply concatenating a suffix e.g.  `#bts;2` did not prove reliable for me with page almost always defaulting to default tab of `#1X2;2`. Below clicks/use of events are deployed to achieve the required navigation
5. Apply condition based waits for content to be present with a timed loop demonstrated as well as a loop waiting for change in attribute value
6. Reduce I/O and significantly boost execution time by storing results in an array and writing that array, `results`, out once to the sheet. Writing an item at a time to the sheet is an expensive I/O operation
7. Use faster CSS selectors which modern browsers are optimised for

---

**Caveats:**

- Tested with all links but there is scope for tightening up the code
- It is likely you may need to have a condition based wait for each event (clicking/FireEvent) on the page. I have demonstrated a variety of these.

---

**Example contents of results array (1 index expanded) :**

[image]

Empty indices are deliberately left to reflect desired output format. One additional column for `country` is added at end.

---

**Example output:**

[image]

---

**Requirements:**

1. VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub GetOddsInfo()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, url As String, matches()
    Dim i As Long, results(), ws As Worksheet, headers()
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    url = "https://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/20190423/"
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1")
    headers = Array("Jogo", vbNullString, "Home Odds", "Draw odds", "Away Odds", vbNullString, "BTT", _
                    "NBTT", vbNullString, "O2", "U2", vbNullString, "Liga", "Country")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 url

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        matches = GetMatches(url, .document)
        ReDim results(1 To UBound(matches, 1), 1 To 14)

        For i = LBound(matches, 1) To UBound(matches, 1)

            .Navigate2 matches(i, 4)             ' default is "#1X2;2"

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            Dim equipas As String, liga As String, averages As Object, oddH As String, oddD As String, oddA As String
            Dim country As String
            country = matches(i, 1)
            liga = matches(i, 2)
            equipas = matches(i, 3)
            Set averages = .document.querySelectorAll(".aver td")
            oddH = "'" & averages.item(1).innerText 'to ensure odds are correctly formatted on output
            oddD = "'" & averages.item(2).innerText
            oddA = "'" & averages.item(3).innerText
            Set averages = Nothing

            If .document.querySelectorAll("[onclick*='uid\(13\)'], [onmousedown*='uid\(13\)']").Length > 1 Then
                On Error Resume Next
                .document.querySelector("[onclick*='uid\(13\)']").FireEvent "onclick" 'both teams to score
                .document.querySelector("[onmousedown*='uid\(13\)']").FireEvent "onmousedown"
                On Error GoTo 0

                While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

                Dim oddBtts  As String, oddNbtts As String, t As Date

                t = Timer
                Do
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set averages = .document.querySelectorAll(".aver td")
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
                Loop While averages.Length < 2

                If averages.Length > 1 Then
                    oddBtts = "'" & averages.item(1).innerText
                    oddNbtts = "'" & averages.item(2).innerText
                End If
            Else
                oddBtts = "No odds"
                oddNbtts = "No odds"
            End If
            Set averages = Nothing
            Dim oddOver As String, oddUnder As String

            If .document.querySelector("#bettype-tabs li:nth-of-type(5)").getAttribute("style") = "display: block;" Then

                .document.querySelector("#bettype-tabs li:nth-of-type(5) span").FireEvent "onmousedown" 'over/under

                Do
                Loop Until .document.querySelector(".table-chunk-header-dark").getAttribute("style") = "display: block;"

               If .document.querySelectorAll("[onclick*='P-2.50-0-0']").Length = 0 Then
                   oddOver = "No odds"
                   oddUnder = "No odds"
               Else

                .document.querySelector("[onclick*='P-2.50-0-0']").Click

                While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend


                Set averages = .document.querySelectorAll(".aver td")
                oddOver = "'" & averages.item(2).innerText
                oddUnder = "'" & averages.item(3).innerText

                End If

            Else
                oddOver = "No odds"
                oddUnder = "No odds"
            End If

            Set averages = Nothing

            Dim resultsPositions(), resultsOrder(), j As Long
            resultsPositions = Array(1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14) 'columns in output
            resultsOrder = Array(equipas, oddH, oddD, oddA, oddBtts, oddNbtts, oddOver, oddUnder, liga, country)

            For j = LBound(resultsPositions) To UBound(resultsPositions)
                results(i, resultsPositions(j)) = resultsOrder(j)
            Next
            'If i = 5 Then Stop                   ''for testing
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetMatches(ByVal url As String, ByVal doc As Object) As Variant
    Dim results(), i As Long, listings As Object, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim countries(), liga As String, country As String, equipas As String, include As Boolean
    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    countries = Array("Argentina", "Austria", "Belgium", "Brazil", "China", "Denmark", "England", _
                      "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Ireland", "Italy", "Japan", "Netherlands", "Norway", _
                      "Poland", "Portugal", "Russia", "Scotland", "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Turkey", "USA")

    Set listings = doc.querySelectorAll("#table-matches tr")
    Dim games As Object, r As Long
    Set games = doc.querySelectorAll(".table-participant a")
    ReDim results(1 To games.Length, 1 To 4)     'country, liga, equipas, url

    For i = 0 To listings.Length - 1
        html.body.innerHTML = listings.item(i).innerHTML
        Select Case listings.item(i).className
        Case "dark center"
            country = Trim$(html.querySelector(".bfl").innerText)
            liga = html.querySelector(".bflp + a").innerText
            include = Not IsError(Application.Match(country, countries, 0))
        Case "odd deactivate"
            If include Then
                r = r + 1
                results(r, 1) = country
                results(r, 2) = liga
                results(r, 3) = html.querySelector("a").innerText
                results(r, 4) = Replace$(html.querySelector("a").href, "about:", "https://www.oddsportal.com")
            End If
        Case " deactivate"
            If include Then
                r = r + 1
                results(r, 1) = country
                results(r, 2) = liga
                results(r, 3) = html.querySelector("a").innerText
                results(r, 4) = Replace$(html.querySelector("a").href, "about:", "https://www.oddsportal.com")
            End If
        End Select
    Next
    results = Application.Transpose(results)
    ReDim Preserve results(1 To UBound(results, 1), 1 To r)
    results = Application.Transpose(results)
    GetMatches = results
End Function
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192714/discussion-on-answer-by-qharr-how-to-solve-error-70-permission-denied).

Comment: Really thank you for your help ! You're a genious :) the code works really well !

Comment: I run the code and didn't show me error . What bug have?

Comment: I will test now the code and then i give you feedback , but you do an amazing job , you improve my code so much ! Really thank you for the help .

Comment: One question, if some day i want to just filter the main leagues of each country i only need switch in the function "GetMatches" right ?

Comment: Main leagues is for example England Premier League, France League 1 , Spain La Liga , etc

Comment: I run the code and finished now , but didn't show me one game : https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/france/ligue-1/nimes-bordeaux-dII5jA9G/ . Really strange

Comment: Completely missed

Comment: Hmm i actually know what is the problem . For example "Portugal - Campeonato de Portugal" , what happens is : copy first game, then second missed, copy third game, then fourth game missed, etc...

Comment: If the table looks like this : https://prnt.sc/njkeem then copy odds alternately, but if the table looks like this: https://prnt.sc/njkevo then copy all the odds correctly

Comment: Just updated :) My next challenge will be see only certain leagues in that countries :)

Comment: Edit doesn't look quite right. I can see the addition of another case which will never be reached because it has the same value as the case before.

Comment: Sorry , you were right , i forgot to switch to only " deactivate"

Comment: Yes now i will try do other code alone for learn more ( using this ) to only check some leagues in that countrys . Again really thank you for your help ! You were really helpfull and kind person !

Comment: It shows me another error don't know why . Should appear "No Odds" in this game 

https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/norway/norway-cup-women/bryne-gimletroll-6DLVH8pe/#over-under;2 
but brower stop in show me error 424 : object required

Comment: I think is cause doesn't appear over 2.5 for this game and in code stops in that part. Maybe cause is looping and doesn't stop because we can't find the odds "Do
                Loop Until .document.querySelector(".table-chunk-header-dark").getAttribute("style") = "display: block;"

                .document.querySelector("[onclick*='P-2.50-0-0']").Click"

Comment: which exact line does it stop on? This is my debug script where you insert a single failing url : https://pastebin.com/nmJVRgHS That runs without fail for me which makes me think timing issue in loop (error will only sometimes pop up). If that is the case I need to know the exact failing line to add additional wait condition.

Comment: In my script executed over all urls it stops in that game and particulary in the line of over 2.5 on the loop

Comment: 1) please paste the exact failing code line (the code) here 2) Does your script fail everytime or sometimes ? (I thought it was working?)

Comment: The code is working really well , but stops ( don't know why) in that particularly game on over 3.5 and then i thought that if the browser stops in that page then maybe the code stop in the loop for over 2.5

Comment: Do
                Loop Until .document.querySelector(".table-chunk-header-dark").getAttribute("style") = "display: block;"

Comment: No , because when the page stops in that url only shows me the error 424 object required

Comment: Again showed me that error : 424 object required, but only appears to click on "ok" or "help" , not debug 
https://prnt.sc/nk1ayw

Comment: I think i solved the problem . will test in more days for see if works

Comment: i switch the line ".document.querySelector("[onclick*='P-2.50-0-0']").Click"
to: On Error Resume Next 
.document.querySelector("[onclick*='P-2.50-0-0']").Click
 On Error GoTo 0 " but in this game he gives me the odd of over 3.5 and i don't want this , so isn't working

Comment: Should i just put "On Error GoTo 0" and cut "On Error Resume Next" ?

Comment: that line doesn't click on over 2.5 if exists over 2.5 ?

Comment: but like i said before , when show me error , don't show me the button for debug , so i don't see where gets highlighted in yellow https://prnt.sc/nk1ayw

Comment: This method you can use instead to go to error line: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36554214/6241235 Trap the error with an Error handler. Follow steps as described in that answer.

Comment: i can't open that pastebin, i create an account and still can't open

Comment: I switched one thing in vba and know appears debug,  wait i will run the code , then i tell you were highlighted in yellow on error

Comment: Now stops here " .Document.querySelector("[onmousedown*='uid\(13\)']").FireEvent "onmousedown" " ... I really don't understand this xD stops in that link https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/argentina/primera-b-nacional/ca-mitre-santiago-del-estero-almagro-nmJPChXS/#bts;2

Comment: https://prnt.sc/nklob8 When shows me the error i click in debug and after f8 and still show me highlighted in yellow only that line

Comment: https://prnt.sc/nklome "interromper em todos os erros" is  the same as "break on all errors"

Comment: The problem is that line for sure , cause i eliminate that line and code works

Comment: And have other error the code, because if in some urls that doesn't have over 2.5 but have for example over 3.5 the code show me error here ".document.querySelector("[onclick*='P-2.50-0-0']").Click"

Comment: I didn't see that case when running. But it is easy to solve. Where are you finding an example for this too fail? Which url?

Comment: waiit i will run and send u url

Comment: https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/norway/division-3-group-1-2019/spjelkavik-herd-082q0Ir2/#over-under;2

Comment: Can you help me fix this problem ? I can't solve that :/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I already see you help a lot of people and don't have time to help me more , so don't worry, i will try alone . Good luck helping people !

Comment: I will look at this again. Don't worry. I don't like leaving questions unfinished. This one will take more time and thought though as I am not getting the error when I run it.

Comment: Try switch for day 23 of that month and see if shows errors on your excel

Comment: yes now this script solves the problem of if doesn't exist over 2.5 but exists others overs. But still have one error on ".Document.querySelector("[onmousedown*='uid\(13\)']").FireEvent "onmousedown" "

Comment: This is wrapped in an On Error so no error should be reported during run and "no odds" should returned.  The above version ran with no problem for me. You need break on unhandled errors (something like _quebrar em erros não tratados_) in settings

Comment: Now doesn't show me error :) i have switched in settings to "break on all errors" for see the debug option , now i switch again to "break on unhandled errors" and code works ! Thanks man

Comment: Let's hope it is finally answered! Lol. We will see. Give it a few days and see. If still working then maybe accept answer.